# object reference error in gridview find control

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i am getting error of Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

the error is coming on the following line

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("empname", empname);
```

and this is how i did the coding of findcontrol

```
    GridViewRow grdupd = grdemp.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    studentclass std = new studentclass();
    Label empid = (Label)grdupd.FindControl("lblempid");
    TextBox empname = (TextBox)grdupd.FindControl("txtname");
```

and here is my gridview

```
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Employee Name">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblname" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("empname") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtname" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("empname") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

what is wrong in my code and why i am  getting the error of null reference and why i am not able to pass data from gridview to backend

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: correct your title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the error is in below line as you say then definitely you haven't declared `SqlCommand` object saying `SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(...)`and so the error

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("empname", empname);
```

Also, as commented by Steen; you are actually adding the `TextBox` control as parameter whereas you should use the `Text` property to do so like

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("empname", empname.Text);
```

Comment: There's also the matter of them trying to add a textbox as a parameter to a sql command, rather than the *value* of the textbox. But that's hardly their biggest issue.